# postsql trouble when populating a table with comma separator

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to populate a table, and I have values with "," from my array "name". so This is not working, if I use something other than a comma separator, it says

```
BadCopyFileFormat: missing data for column
```

```
s = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tokens (address varchar(100) NOT NULL,symbol varchar(100) NOT NULL,name varchar(100) NOT NULL)"
db_cursor.execute(s)

with open('data/tokens.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    next(f)  # Skip the header row.
    db_cursor.copy_from(f, 'tokens', sep=',')
    db_conn.commit()
```

My data look like

```
address symbol name
x23fva3  ABC    ABC
2vajd83  DAP    
29vb4h2  Wink   Jamal, ab
2jsbg93  x3     xon3
```

Is there a way to populate the table with missing values??

Comment: 1) I am not seeing a `name` array. 2) Provide a short example of the data in the file. 3) Define 'missing values'?  Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: i just did, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I got to work:

```
cat data/tokens.csv 

address |symbol|name
x23fva3 | ABC | ABC
2vajd83 | DAP |    
29vb4h2 | Wink | Jamal, ab
2jsbg93 | x3 | xon3

with open('data/tokens.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    next(f)  # Skip the header row.
    db_cursor.copy_from(f, 'tokens', sep='|')
    db_conn.commit()

select * from tokens ;
 address  | symbol |    name    
----------+--------+------------
 x23fva3  |  ABC   |  ABC
 2vajd83  |  DAP   |     
 29vb4h2  |  Wink  |  Jamal, ab
 2jsbg93  |  x3    |  xon3
```

I use the pipe(`|`) regularly for this sort of thing as it very rarely shows up in data on its own.

**UPDATE**

For a file with empty values there needs to still be a separator for each field like:

```
address |symbol|name
x23fva3 | ABC | ABC
2vajd83 | DAP |    
32vb4h3 |     |
1jsbg94 |     | xon3
```

Comment: when i use sep =' | ', i get another error msg: BadCopyFileFormat: missing data for column "symbol"

Comment: Did you change the CSV file to have the `|` separator?

Comment: I am so sorry, how do you do that?

Comment: I took '...if I use something other than a comma separator ...' to mean you could change the separator. Are you generating the CSV file or is coming from somewhere else?

Comment: it is coming from somewhere else. I download this big dataset and it uses , as a separator.  What I meant by "something other than a comma separator.." is changing the code, exactly what you suggested, replacing sep',' with | or ; or anything. I get "missing data for column" error msg

Comment: A) The data you show does not have `,` separator, the values are separated by space. B) `sep=` has to match the separator in the file. As of now from what you show the CSV file is poorly formatted. Can get the source to change their output?

Comment: I managed to change the separator to |, and now it is giving me the missing value error. I have a lot of missing values for the symbol and name columns. Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: See my UPDATE to answer.